# PySimpleGui - how do you remove text from input text box

Tags: python, pysimplegui

How do you clear text in an input box PySimpleGui? I'm trying window ['-INPUT-'] ('') but I recieve a key error. I want it so that the text in the box gets replaced with an empty string after each iteration so the user doesn't have to delete the text themselves.

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: Most of time, it was caused you didn't have an element instantiated with option `key='-IINPUT-'` or `k='-IINPUT-'`.

Comment: @Jason Yang I have defined it the layout section so I it update on the UI

Comment: @quamrana yea I should of done that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want it so that the text in the box gets replaced with an empty
> string after each iteration so the user doesn't have to delete the
> text themselves.

Ah!

There is a parameter meant specifically for this purpose.

Set `do_not_clear=False`

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [  [sg.Text('Input element that clears after every read')],
            [sg.Input('Initial text', key='-I-', do_not_clear=False)],
            [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')] ]

window = sg.Window('Input auto-clear', layout)

while True:             # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):
        break
    print(event, values)
window.close()
```