# PySimpleGui - how to remove text from input text box?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

`input2 = sg.InputText("Message", do_not_clear=False)` 
made a little program and want to automatically clear the field whenever the field is clicked on

Tried:
`do_not_clear=False` 
Doesn't work. Still have to delete the message manually from the field to type

how to remove text from input text box?

Comment: See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68691097) which shows code to clear a text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using method `bind` of element to bind the event `'<FocusIn>'` to generate an event.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Input('Initial text', key='IN1')],
    [sg.Input('Initial text', key='IN2')],
    [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')],
]

window = sg.Window('Input auto-clear', layout, use_default_focus=False, finalize=True)
window['IN1'].bind('<FocusIn>', ' FOCUS')

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'IN1 FOCUS':
        window['IN1'].update('')
        window['IN2'].update('')

window.close()
```